# Ruby; How can I update the nested hashes in this one?

Tags: ruby

Sorry, it's a little bit too long. I need to change the status of :hero and :heroine to "dead"

```
def update_status
   epic_tragedy = {
      :montague => {
         :patriarch => {name: "Lord Montague", age: "53"},
         :matriarch => {name: "Lady Montague", age: "54"},
         :hero => {name: "Romeo", age: "15", status: "alive"},
         :hero_friends => [
            {name: "Benvolio", age: "17", attitude: "worried"},
            {name: "Mercutio", age: "18", attitude: "hot-headed"}
         ]
      },
      :capulet => {
         :patriarch => {name: "Lord Capulet", age: "50"},
         :matriarch => {name: "Lady Capulet", age: "51"},
         :heroine => {name: "Juliet", age: "15", status: "alive"},
         :heroine_friends => [
         {name: "Steven", age: "30", attitude: "confused"},
         {name: "Nurse", age: "44", attitude: "worried"}
         ]
      }
   }
```

I did add the code below inside the method but it shows error.

epic_tragedy[:montague][:hero][:status] = "dead"

epic_tragedy[:capulet][:hero][:status] = "dead"

Is there any additional step before I put those lines?

Comment: Julie was no hero in death, but I guess she could be regarded as a heroine.

Comment: Why are you using a version of Ruby on Rails that has been unmaintained for years and has known, unpatched security vulnerabilities? And what does this even have to do with Ruby on Rails at all?

Answer (score 1):

`epic_tragedy` is a local variable within the method definition. Such local variables cannot be accessed from outside the method.

However, the hash is returned when the method is executed, so try

```
h = update_status
  #=> {:montague=>{
  #      :patriarch=>{:name=>"Lord Montague", :age=>"53"},
  #      :matriarch=>{:name=>"Lady Montague", :age=>"54"},
  #      :hero=>{:name=>"Romeo", :age=>"15", :status=>"alive"},
  #      :hero_friends=>[
  #        {:name=>"Benvolio", :age=>"17", :attitude=>"worried"},
  #        {:name=>"Mercutio", :age=>"18", :attitude=>"hot-headed"}
  #      ]
  #    },
  #    :capulet=>{
  #      :patriarch=>{:name=>"Lord Capulet", :age=>"50"},
  #      :matriarch=>{:name=>"Lady Capulet", :age=>"51"},
  #      :heroine=>{:name=>"Juliet", :age=>"15", :status=>"alive"},
  #      :heroine_friends=>[
  #        {:name=>"Steven", :age=>"30", :attitude=>"confused"},
  #        {:name=>"Nurse", :age=>"44", :attitude=>"worried"}
  #      ]
  #    }
  #   }
```

```
h[:montague][:hero][:status] = "dead"
h[:capulet][:heroine][:status] = "dead"
```

```
h #=> {:montague=>{
  #      :patriarch=>{:name=>"Lord Montague", :age=>"53"},
  #      :matriarch=>{:name=>"Lady Montague", :age=>"54"},
  #      :hero=>{:name=>"Romeo", :age=>"15", :status=>"dead"},
  #      :hero_friends=>[
  #        {:name=>"Benvolio", :age=>"17", :attitude=>"worried"},
  #        {:name=>"Mercutio", :age=>"18", :attitude=>"hot-headed"}
  #      ]
  #    },
  #    :capulet=>{
  #      :patriarch=>{:name=>"Lord Capulet", :age=>"50"},
  #      :matriarch=>{:name=>"Lady Capulet", :age=>"51"},
  #      :heroine=>{:name=>"Juliet", :age=>"15", :status=>"dead"},
  #      :heroine_friends=>[
  #        {:name=>"Steven", :age=>"30", :attitude=>"confused"},
  #        {:name=>"Nurse", :age=>"44", :attitude=>"worried"}
  #      ]
  #    }
  #   }
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: If you got the error message, `"SyntaxError: unexpected end-of-input, expecting 'end'"` it's because you did not include the missing `end` statement for the method `update_status`? In any event, when you report an error in an SO question you need to state the exact error message, including the line in which the exception was raised. You will agree that "didn't work" is not very informative.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on SO. Yes, `end` is there.  The test fails with the following message.                                                                                                        `update_status returns a hash where the hero and heroine's status is set to dead
     Failure/Error: expect(update_status[:montague][:hero][:status]).to eq("dead")
     
       expected: "dead"
            got: "alive"
     
       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/updating_nested_hashes_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' `

Comment: Your error message appears to be related to a test of the code that you are performing and probably refers to the test code (`RSpec`?) as opposed to the code I have shown above. Since your question does not include the testing code readers cannot help you with that. Try running the code above in IRB. I ran it and it does work. If you are having a problem with code testing you may wish to submit a separate question.